# Поменял название пакета, приложение android не открывается, ошибка

Tags: java, android, google-play

Загружаю в play market приложение, app-release.apk, при загрузке в play market выходила ошибка, поменять имя пакета com.examlpe на другое, через refacror поменял example в имени пакета на другое, при отладке на сматфоне вылетает ошибка и всё, что когда устанавливаю app-debug.apk или app-release.apk, как исправить?

Comment: Какая ошибка вылетает?

Comment: Попробуйте сначала сделать отладку и посмотреть, что происходит.
Какие ошибки и т.д.

Comment: В `build.gradle` поменяй `applicationId`

Comment: надо проверить build.gradle приложения и AndroidManifest.xml чтобы имя пакета везде совпадало